# Android SMS count database

Tags: android, database, android-layout, android-intent, sms

I am looking for code to get the total sent-sms count in android mobiles. If I use `content://sms/sent/` for querying the database I get the sms count of the available sent sms in the mobile, but I want the total sms that is sent from buying the  mobile.

Comment: https://373329952-smack.googlecode.com/hg-history/2440b585ea87ccd88fc5f9045b70471d9617f38e/src/com/googlecode/gtalksms/cmd/smsCmd/SmsMmsManager.java this link help you..

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve All SMS messages in the Android

The URI `(content://sms/)` will used to retrive the all SMS messages, also we can split up by the message type as well as.

```
Uri allMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(allMessage, null, null, null, null);
while  (c.moveToNext()) {
  String row = c.getString(1);
}
```

you can get the all inbox/outbox here

Comment: it is fine but it brings only the available sms count in the database. suppose if i delete some messages , message count is also deleted,but i want all the sms count from my first sms of my mobile.

Comment: how it is possible. I think its not possible to count like that. for suppose if the count is maintained like that also . if you reset your mobile completely then all the data will be deleted. So I think only available sms will be displayed.

Comment: if u have a doubt in the possibility pls download smscount app in google play market. it does the thing i want to do ? how is that possible ??

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kknd.android.smscounter&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5ra25kLmFuZHJvaWQuc21zY291bnRlciJd

Answer (score -1):

change your URI
use this one: content://sms/